# Is there any GPU based Matlab toolbox for deep learning?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am looking for a GPU based Deep Learning library for matlab. Do you know any or any suggestions that matter?

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/parallel-computing.html). It explains how to use GPU's in Neural Networks' training.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try [skaae/DeepLearnToolbox](https://github.com/skaae/DeepLearnToolbox). It is a fork from [rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox) and has some added functionality for GPU. It is still under development so reply if it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe it is my bad but I cannot see and GPU utilization at least on Readme explanations

Comment: The skaae and rasmusbergpalm have the same Readme and it does not tell of the GPU utilisation. Files for GPU are in NN folder https://github.com/skaae/DeepLearnToolbox/tree/master/NN and SAE folder https://github.com/skaae/DeepLearnToolbox/tree/master/SAE

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried the two solutions that are mentioned in a previous answer. But I can attest that [matconvnet](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/) is superb. It has both CPU and GPU implementations. It has been tested to compile and run on a gpu on both linux, mac and windows. Its code is very readable, and it supports arbitrary changes to the network's topology.

On top of it all, the code includes ample examples for training solution on known datasets (MNIST, imagenet), and provides some pretrained networks that are consistent with caffe's implementation to numerical precision.

I'm not affiliated with matconvnet creators in any way, by the way. Just a fan :-)